# Не работает функция toupper

Tags: c++, строки

Программа компилируется но текст не переводит. Причём не работает что с подключенными библиотеками ctype что без них. tolower тоже не работает

```
void strToUpper(string &line)
{
for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
    if (islower(line[i]))
        toupper(line[i]);
}
void strToLower(string &line)
{
for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
    if (isupper(line[i]))
        tolower(line[i]);
}
void main()
{
int selecter;
string line;
cout << "Enter line:";
getline(cin, line);
cout << "Select (1-upper, 2-lower)\n";
cin >> selecter;
if (selecter == 1)
   strToUpper(line);
else if (selecter == 2)
    strToLower(line);
else
{
    cout << "ERROR!";
    return;
}
cout << line << "\n\n\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Всех благодарю!

Answer (score 3):

В `tolower/toupper` буква передается по значению, а не по ссылке.

Вызывайте как

```
c = toupper(c);
```

Кстати, [вот еще вариант для строки](https://ideone.com/uUtbSD)...

Answer (score 1):

Конечно не переводит, ведь результат перевода вы игнорируете. Должно быть так:

```
line[i] = static_cast<char>(toupper(line[i]));
```